# How install Marketing Segmentation in Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition 12c

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

in my Obiee 12 there isn't the application/package called 'Marketing Segmentation'. How can I install it? That's why I can't create a segment.
There is a simple method to do it or I need to modify instanceconfig.xml?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled by default. For 12.2.1.4 (no idea what "12c" you are on) you need to enable it by following https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2458323.1

Comment: Sorry but clicking on link, give me this:                                                                 
Document cannot be displayed. Possible reasons are:

The document id was entered incorrectly. Please check and try again.
The document id does not exist (was referenced incorrectly).
The document is not classified as publicly accessible ("non-public").
The content is being updated and it is temporarily unavailable but will be made available again soon.

If you still have questions about why you could not access this article or bug, please use Contact Us.

Comment: Do you have a valid login? Because it works as soon as I click on it.

Comment: Uhm, yes because I can enter on my profile and I can see that my user is activated

Comment: Then just search for the ID 2458323.1 once you're logged on to support.oracle.com and it will come up